# How To Handle the Image in Android,IOS and Websites?

Tags: php, android, ios, image

I looked many websites and android applications like swiggy,dominos etc..

How They are Handled the images as light weight(small size and better quality and responsive for all devices).

What type of images they are used like jpg,png etc...

Comment: What has that to do with MySql and MongoDB?

Comment: save format only image url or like base64 converted format

Comment: Compress your images and reduce its size below 100kb. There are lots of tools which does not make the effect on resolution while compressing it. Most loved format is jpg/png I think. Now user NSCache in your app (iOS) to handle the images.

Comment: what bout android and php based websites?

Answer (score 0):

There are many compressing libraries available on GitHub. I personally used 
 implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'.
The use is pretty simple too.

```
File compressedFile= null;
        try {
                        compressedFile = new Compressor(this).compressToFile(file);
                        compressedFileUri = Uri.fromFile(compressedFile);
                        UploadImage(compressedFileUri);
                        imageButton.setImageURI(compressedFileUri);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e("EditProfile","image compression error",e.getCause());
                    }
```

file here is the file to be compressed. 
The compressedFileUri can now be used as a reference to compressed file and can be uploaded either as multipart file or base64. (I used firebase so, it became more simple) It converted my file from 400 kb to 80 kb retaining the quality.

Comment: If u like the answer, u can upvote it to show usefulness.